# ruby alphanumeric sort not working as expected

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, alphanumeric

Given the following array:

```
y = %w[A1 A2 B5 B12 A6 A8 B10 B3 B4 B8]
=> ["A1", "A2", "B5", "B12", "A6", "A8", "B10", "B3", "B4", "B8"]
```

With the expected sorted array to be:

```
=> ["A1", "A2", "A6", "A8", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B8", "B10", "B12"]
```

Using the following (vanilla) sort, I get:

```
irb(main):2557:0> y.sort{|a,b| puts "%s <=> %s = %s\n" % [a, b, a <=> b]; a <=> b}
A1 <=> A8 = -1
A8 <=> B8 = -1
A2 <=> A8 = -1
B5 <=> A8 = 1
B4 <=> A8 = 1
B3 <=> A8 = 1
B10 <=> A8 = 1
B12 <=> A8 = 1
A6 <=> A8 = -1
A1 <=> A2 = -1
A2 <=> A6 = -1
B12 <=> B3 = -1
B3 <=> B8 = -1
B5 <=> B3 = 1
B4 <=> B3 = 1
B10 <=> B3 = -1  # this appears to be wrong, looks like 1 is being compared, not 10.
B12 <=> B10 = 1
B5 <=> B4 = 1
B4 <=> B8 = -1
B5 <=> B8 = -1
=> ["A1", "A2", "A6", "A8", "B10", "B12", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B8"]
```

...which is obviously not what I desire. I know I can attempt to split on the alpha first and then sort the numerical, but it just seems like I shouldn't have to do that.

Possible big caveat: we're stuck using Ruby 1.8.7 for now :( But even Ruby 2.0.0 is doing the same thing. What am I missing here?

Suggestions?

Comment: Your first hunch is the correct one; since these are strings, they're going to be ordered lexicographically.  If you want to take the number into account as an element of the ordering, you will need to separate the letter from the number and use it of its own volition when sorting.

Comment: I'm curious why you think the *string* "B12" would be sorted before the *string* "B2". This isn't how Ruby sorts strings, this is how *everything* sorts strings.

Comment: You want `y.sort_by { |s| [s[0], s[1..-1].to_i] } #=> ["A1", "A2", "A6", "A8", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B8", "B10", "B12"]`. See [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for how Ruby sorts arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are sorting strings. Strings are sorted like strings, not like numbers. If you want to sort like numbers, then you should sort numbers, not strings. The string `'B10'` is lexicographically smaller than the string `'B3'`, that's not something unique to Ruby, that's not even something unique to programming, that's how lexicographically sorting a piece of text works pretty much everywhere, in programming, databases, lexicons, dictionaries, phonebooks, etc.

You should split your strings into their numerical and non-numerical components, and convert the numerical components to numbers. Array sorting is lexicographic, so this will end up sorting exactly right:

```
y.sort_by {|s| # use `sort_by` for a keyed sort, not `sort`
  s.
    split(/(\d+)/). # split numeric parts from non-numeric
    map {|s| # the below parses numeric parts as decimals, ignores the rest
      begin Integer(s, 10); rescue ArgumentError; s end }}
#=> ["A1", "A2", "A6", "A8", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B8", "B10", "B12"]
```

Comment: Instead of handling an exception for each non-numeric sub-string, you could convert it conditionally, e.g. by checking whether it starts with a digit `s =~ /^\d/ ? s.to_i : s`

Comment: [Kernel::Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) was changed in v2.6 to add an optional argument. If `exception: true` is included as an argument, `nil` is returned if the conversion to an integer fails. That would allow you to write `y.sort_by {|s| s.split(/(\d+)/).map {|e| Integer(e, exception: false) || e}} #=> ["A1", "A2", "A6", "A8", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B8", "B10", "B12"]`.

Comment: I see the `:exception` option was also added to `Kernel::Complex`, `Kernel::Float` and `Kernel::Rational` in v2.6.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for pointing this out. I’m aware of the `exception` keyword, but The OP specifically asked for a 1.8.7 compliant solution.

Comment: @Stefan, true, but our job is to not just help the asker and the asker may one day upgrade from the steam-driven v1.8.7. By all means give a solution that works with v1.8.7, but it does no harm to also show how the solution can be simplified when using later versions.

Comment: Yeah, as the OP, 1.8.7 was the version used at the time. It's good to see the newer models as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to do that.

```
arr = ["A1", "A2", "B5", "B12", "A6", "AB12", "A8", "B10", "B3", "B4",
       "B8", "AB2"]
```

**Sort on a 2-element array**

```
arr.sort_by { |s| [s[/\D+/], s[/\d+/].to_i] }
  #=> ["A1", "A2", "A6", "A8", "AB2", "AB12", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B8",
  #    "B10", "B12"]
```

This is similar to @Jorg's solution except I've computed the two elements of the comparison array separately, rather than splitting the string into two parts and converting the latter to an integer.

[Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) compares each pair of elements of `arr` with the spaceship method, `<=>`. As the elements being compared are arrays, the method [Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) is used. See in particular the third paragraph of that doc.

`sort_by` compares the following 2-element arrays:

```
arr.each { |s| puts "%s-> [%s, %d]" %
  ["\"#{s}\"".ljust(7), "\"#{s[/\D+/]}\"".ljust(4), s[/\d+/].to_i] }

"A1"   -> ["A" , 1]
"A2"   -> ["A" , 2]
"B5"   -> ["B" , 5]
"B12"  -> ["B" , 12]
"A6"   -> ["A" , 6]
"AB12" -> ["AB", 12]
"A8"   -> ["A" , 8]
"B10"  -> ["B" , 10]
"B3"   -> ["B" , 3]
"B4"   -> ["B" , 4]
"B8"   -> ["B" , 8]
"AB2"  -> ["AB", 2]
```

**Insert spaces between the alphameric and numeric parts of the string**

```
max_len = arr.max_by(&:size).size
  #=> 4
arr.sort_by { |s| "%s%s%d" % [s[/\D+/], " "*(max_len-s.size), s[/\d+/].to_i] }
  #=> ["A1", "A2", "A6", "A8", "AB2", "AB12", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B8",
  #    "B10", "B12"]
```

Here `sort_by` compares the following strings:

```
arr.each { |s| puts "%s-> \"%s\"" %
  ["\"#{s}\"".ljust(7), s[/\D+/] + " "*(max_len-s.size) + s[/\d+/]] }

"A1"   -> "A  1"
"A2"   -> "A  2"
"B5"   -> "B  5"
"B12"  -> "B 12"
"A6"   -> "A  6"
"AB12" -> "AB12"
"A8"   -> "A  8"
"B10"  -> "B 10"
"B3"   -> "B  3"
"B4"   -> "B  4"
"B8,"  -> "B 8"
"AB2"  -> "AB 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the maximum amount of digits in your numbers is you can also prefix your numbers with `0` during comparison.

```
y.sort_by { |string| string.gsub(/\d+/) { |digits| format('%02d', digits.to_i) } }
#=> ["A1", "A2", "A6", "A8", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B8", "B10", "B12"]
```

Here `'%02d'` specifies the following, the `%` denotes the formatting of a value, the `0` then specifies to prefix the number with `0`s, the `2` specifies the total length of the number, the `d` specifies that you want the output in decimals (base 10). You can find additional info [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format).

This means that `'A1'` will be converted to `'A01'`, `'B8'` will become `'B08'` and `'B12'` will stay `'B12'`, since it already has 2 digits. This is only used during comparison.

Answer (score -1):

A natural or lexicographic sort, not a standard character-value-based sort, would be needed. Something like these gems would be a starting point: https://github.com/dogweather/naturally, https://github.com/johnnyshields/naturalsort

Humans treat a string like "A2" as "A" followed by the number 2, and sort by using character-string sorting for the string part and numeric sorting for the numeric part. Standard `sort()` uses character-value sorting treating the string as a sequence of characters regardless of what the characters are. So for `sort()` "A10" and "A2" look like [ 'A', '1', '0' ] and [ 'A', '2' ], since '1' sorts before '2' and the following characters can't change that order "A10" thus sorts before "A2". For humans the same strings look like [ "A", 10 ] and [ "A", 2 ], 10 sorts after 2 so we get the opposite result. The strings can be manipulated to make the character-value-based `sort()` produce the expected result by making the numeric portion fixed-width and zero-padding it on the left to avoid embedded spaces, making "A2" turn into "A02" which does sort before "A10" using standard `sort()`.

Comment: This actually solves the problem, but it doesn't explain why the sort doesn't work out of the box. Very interesting, though.

Comment: Numeric values sort differently than the character-by-character sorting of their string representations. A character-value sort doesn't work for eg. "A10" and "A2" because the character value for '1' is less than for '2' and that makes "A10" sort before "A2". A natural sort, OTOH, would interpret "A2" as equivalent to "A02" or [ "A", 2 ] (the way we'd treat it, as "A" followed by the number 2).

Comment: NB: the above is why you see numbers right-justified in fixed-width fixed-decimal-position zero-padded fields so often in data files, so that the character sort matches the results of a numeric sort.

Comment: "A natural or lexicographic sort, not a standard character-value-based sort, would be needed." - Ruby *is* doing a lexicographic sort, that is precisely what the OP does *not* want.