# Sort Alphanumerically Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

So I have an array of strings that:

```
["A", "B", "BF1", "BF5", "BF16", "C", "C10", "C2", "D"]
```

I want this to be sorted to:

```
["A", "B", "BF1", "BF5", "BF16", "C", "C2", "C10", "D"]
```

Ruby's Array#sort produces:

```
["A", "B", "BF1", "BF16", "BF5", "C", "C10", "C2", "D"]
```

where "BF16" comes before "BF5" which is inaccurate

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023861/ruby-alphanumeric-sort-not-working-as-expected

Comment: `["A", "B", "BF1", "BF5", "BF16", "C", "C10", "C2", "D"].sort_by {|s| s.split(/(\d+)/).map {|s| begin Integer(s, 10); rescue ArgumentError; s end }}`

Comment: @SafwanSM everyone here knows how to follow a link, there's no need to copy an answer.

Comment: ""BF16" comes before "BF5" which is inaccurate" - I don't understand. Why is this "inaccurate"? (What does "inaccurate" even mean in this context?) "1" Comes before "5", doesn't it?

Comment: @Stefan oh really??